# Preset Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have an analytics program that receives many values from a HTTP GET request and maps them into a table. My question pertains to changing the shorthand names I assigned to variables in the request into more full names before I write them to a log file. What is the best way for mapping the shorthand (e.g `uid: KG`) to the full names (`User ID: KG` )?

Currently I have a Map that puts all the relations in it (`"uid": "User ID"`) on runtime. It uses a good number of calls to put every value in the map so I was wondering what is standard practice or most efficient, many put calls or is there a way to save a standard map to a file and load it in runtime?

Comment: Well if the map doesn't change then just initialize it once in a static block.

Comment: That's how I currently have it, just wondering if there is a more efficient method than hard coding that many `map.put("shorthand","full name")` calls

Comment: If you hard-code the mappings, you don't need to load them from file, which is good. Creating these mappings are one-time operation, so it should not impact the performance of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load a Properties object from a file is probably your best option.  Instead of hard coding them in your program you can put them in a properties file like so:

uid=User ID
bid=Billy ID
...

THen load them using this API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Sounds like what I'm looking for, thank you. I'll look into it and mark you the correct answer after I implement it in the morning if all goes well.